# How to evaluate an expression when array dimensions are different

Tags: python, numpy, save, matrix-multiplication

I would like to evaluate the following function:

```
inclination=np.pi/6

def power(inclination,phi):
    h1=1.7 
    h2=0.5 
    D = np.arange(0.5, 12.0, 0.1)
    r = np.sqrt((h1-h2)**2 + D**2)
    freq = 865.7 
    lmb = 300/freq 
    H = D**2/(D**2+2*h1*h2)
    theta = 4*np.pi*h1*h2/(lmb*D)
    q_e = H**2*(np.sin(theta))**2 + (1 - H*np.cos(theta))**2
    sigma = 1.94
    N_1 = np.random.normal(0,sigma,D.shape)
    rnd = 10**(-N_1/10)
    F = 10 
    power=0.2
    alpha=inclination + np.arcsin((h1-h2)/r)
    gain=3.136*(np.tan(alpha)*np.sin(np.pi/2*np.cos(alpha)*np.sin(phi)))**2
    y=10*np.log10( 1000*(power*gain*1.622*((lmb)**2) *0.5*1) / (((4*np.pi*r)**2) *1.2*1*F)*q_e*rnd )
    return y
```

The problem is that calling the function returns an error.

```
phi=np.arange(-np.pi/2, np.pi/2, np.pi/32)
power(np.pi/6,phi)

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-268e3287b75a> in <module>()
----> 1 power(np.pi/6,phi)

<ipython-input-30-4b89d23682ce> in power(inclination, phi)
     19 
     20     alpha=inclination + np.arcsin((h1-h2)/r)
---> 21     gain=3.136*(np.tan(alpha)*np.sin(np.pi/2*np.cos(alpha)*np.sin(phi)))**2
     22     print(gain)
     23     y=10*np.log10( 1000*(power*gain*1.622*((lmb)**2) *0.5*1) / (((4*np.pi*r)**2) *1.2*1*F)*q_e*rnd )

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (115,) (32,)
```

probably because it complains about the operation in `gain` line with matrices `alpha` and `phi` of different dimensions. 
The problem is that I would like to use different matrix dimensions, and, save a `txt` file where the first column is `r` the second `phi` and the third the value of  `y`.

Comment: What do you want `gain`'s shape to be? (115,32) or (32,115). [Broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) ... [Array Broadcasting in Numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/theory.broadcasting.html#array-broadcasting-in-numpy)

Comment: What do you mean by `use different matrix dimensions`? If `A` is (5,) shape, and `B` (3,), what is `A*B` supposed to be?

Comment: @wwii Thanks to comment. I would like (115,32) dimension. Do you have a solution?

Comment: @hpaulj Sorry if the expression 'different dimensions' is not correct. I mean the two arrays have not compatible shapes.

Comment: It's not that the description is wrong,  It's that you don't elaborate on what you want to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a dimension to one of the arrays to enable [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

```
>>> alpha = np.ones(115, dtype=np.uint8)
>>> phi = np.ones(32, dtype=np.uint8)

>>> c = alpha[:,None] * phi
>>> alpha.shape, alpha[:,None].shape, phi.shape, c.shape
((115,), (115, 1), (32,), (115, 32))
```

Assuming `alpha.shape` is `(115,)`:
`

```
>>> gain=3.136*(np.tan(alpha[:,None])*np.sin(np.pi/2*np.cos(alpha[:,None])*np.sin(phi)))**2
>>> gain.shape
(115, 32)
```